# Audio output on Raspberry pi Zero W

Tags: raspbian, gpio, audio, pi-zero, pi-zero-w

I was trying to take an audio output from piZero-W, the article I followed was,
[this one](https://learn.adafruit.com/adding-basic-audio-ouput-to-raspberry-pi-zero).

How to get audio through the gpio pins to a 3.5mm jack?

When running - `systemctl status alsa-state`

the result is

```
alsa-state.service - Manage Sound Card State (restore and store)
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/alsa-state.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:alsactl(1)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly you need to build the circuit described in the adafruit article that you linked. https://learn.adafruit.com/adding-basic-audio-ouput-to-raspberry-pi-zero/overview

Here is mine, connected to GND, GPIO12 and GPIO13:

[image]

Then in the /boot/config.txt file you need to add an overlay entry to remap the audio:

```
dtoverlay=audremap,pins_12_13
```

Then in 'sudo raspi-config' configure the audio to Headphones.

Test with:

```
speaker-test -c2
```

Should hear noise from left and right channels.